# android get value base on key in arraylist

Tags: java, android

i got ArrayList as sample below :-

```
<Data><No1><time>16:32</time><Number>2</Number></No1><No2><time>14:32</time><Number>3</Number></No2></Data>
```

How do i get the time value 16:32 base on the time. I don't wants to use substring. Any idea can base on the key time to get value.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//try this way
1. you need "ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> data = new ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String, String>>()" for data
2. your each LinkedHashMap have two key "time" and "number'
3. now one by one store each data item in LinkedHashMap and add each LinkedHashMap to  "ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> data"
4 now access data whatever you want using "ArrayList<LinkedHashMap<String,String>> data" get index wise LinkedHashMap again get value LinkedHashMap  key.
**Note** LinkedHashMap - is store sequential data and HashMap - is store unsequential
```

Answer (score 1):

Use HashMaps
[Se this link for details](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/HashMap.html)